# Error while running web service on blackberry simulator

Tags: java, web-services, blackberry, blackberry-jde

I am trying to access a webservice from a BlackBerry application that I developed.

However, when running the app  I get

> " App Error 104 Uncaught: NullPointerException "

I am unable to debug, for some strange reason my debugger auto-closes as soon as I start debugging.

Any suggestions on what could be the reason? I would like to mention that I have received the three .csi signature files from BlackBerry, but whenever I try to sign the application it fails: **The Signature information in the code signing register request is not of appropriate length**. Could this error be due to signing the application?

This is what I've done so far:

```java
package mypackage;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.util.Hashtable;

import javacard.framework.UserException;

import javax.microedition.io.Connector;
import javax.microedition.io.HttpConnection;
import javax.microedition.location.Location;
import javax.microedition.location.LocationProvider;

import org.kobjects.base64.Base64;
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransport;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;

import net.rim.device.api.system.*;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.*;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.*;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.pane.TitleView;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.*;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.image.Image;
import net.rim.device.api.xml.jaxp.SAXParserImpl;

public class LoginTest extends UiApplication 
{

    public static void main(String[] args)  
    {
         //Create a new instance of the app
         //and start the app on the event thread.

        LoginTest app = new LoginTest();
        app.enterEventDispatcher();
    }

    public LoginTest()
    {
         //Display a new screen.
         pushScreen(new LoginTestScreen());
    }

}

//Create a new screen that extends MainScreen and provides
//behaviour similar to that of other apps.

final class LoginTestScreen extends MainScreen
{
   //declare variables for later use
   private InfoScreen _infoScreen;
   private ObjectChoiceField choiceField;
   private int select;
   BasicEditField username;
   PasswordEditField passwd;
   CheckboxField checkBox1;
   ButtonField loginBtn;

   public LoginTestScreen()
   {
        //Invoke the MainScreen constructor.

        super();

        //Add a screen title.

        setTitle("Track24ELMS");

        LabelField login = new LabelField("ELMS Login", LabelField.FIELD_HCENTER); 
        login.setFont(Font.getDefault().derive(Font.BOLD, 30));
        login.setMargin(10, 0, 20, 0); //To leave some space from top and bottom

        HorizontalFieldManager user = new HorizontalFieldManager();
        user.setMargin(0, 0, 10, 0);
        HorizontalFieldManager pass = new HorizontalFieldManager();
        pass.setMargin(0, 0, 20, 0);
        HorizontalFieldManager checkbox = new HorizontalFieldManager();
        checkbox.setMargin(0, 0, 30, 0);
        HorizontalFieldManager btns = new HorizontalFieldManager(HorizontalFieldManager.FIELD_HCENTER);

        LabelField usernameTxt = new LabelField("Username :");
        LabelField passwordTxt = new LabelField("Password :");

        username = new BasicEditField();
        passwd = new PasswordEditField();

        loginBtn = new ButtonField("Login", ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK); 
        loginBtn.setChangeListener(new LoginButtonListener());

        checkBox1 = new CheckboxField("Remember me",false);

        user.add(usernameTxt);
        user.add(username);
        pass.add(passwordTxt);
        pass.add(passwd);
        //checkbox.add(checkBox1);
        btns.add(loginBtn);
        add(login);
        add(user);
        add(pass);
        add(checkBox1);
        add(btns);
   }

   private class LoginButtonListener implements FieldChangeListener {
       public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
       //Open a new screen
       String uname = username.getText();
       String pwd = passwd.getText();

       //If there is no input
       if (uname.length() == 0 || pwd.length()==0)
       Dialog.alert("One of the textfield is empty!");
       else 
       {
           final String URL = "http://xxx.xxx.com/xxx/xxx.asmx";
           final String METHOD_NAME = "ValidateCredentials";
           final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
           final String SOAP_ACTION = NAMESPACE+METHOD_NAME;
           //final String URL = "http://prerel.track24elms.com/Android/T24AndroidLogin.asmx/ValidateCredentials";

           SoapObject resultRequestSOAP = null;
           HttpConnection httpConn = null;
           HttpTransport httpt;
           System.out.println("The username" + uname + "password" + pwd );
           SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
           request.addProperty("Username", "abc");//First parameter is tag name provided by web service
           request.addProperty("Password", "xyz");
           System.out.println("The request is=======" + request.toString());
           SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
           envelope.bodyOut = request;
           envelope.dotNet = true;
           envelope.encodingStyle = SoapSerializationEnvelope.XSD;
           envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
           System.out.println("The envelope has the value++++"+ envelope.toString());

           /* URL+  Here you can add paramter so that you can run on device,simulator etc. this will work only for wifi */
           httpt = new HttpTransport(URL+ ";deviceside=true;ConnectionUID=S TCP-WiFi");
           httpt.setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
           httpt.debug = true;
           try
           {
               System.out.println("SOAP_ACTION    ==   " + SOAP_ACTION);
               httpt.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
               System.out.println("the tranport" + httpt.toString());
               resultRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
               System.out.println("result    ==   " + resultRequestSOAP);            
           }
           catch (IOException e) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               System.out.println("The exception is IO==" + e.getMessage());
           } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {

               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               System.out.println("The exception xml parser example==="
                       + e.getMessage());
           }
           System.out.println( resultRequestSOAP);
           if(resultRequestSOAP.equals("credentialaccepted"))
           {
           UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new InfoScreen()); //Open a new Screen
           }
           else
           {
               System.out.println("Login details not valid");
           }
         }
      }

   };

   //To display a dialog box when a BlackBerry device user
   //closes the app, override the onClose() method.

   public boolean onClose()
   {
        Dialog.alert("Goodbye!");
        System.exit(0);
        return true;
   }

   //Create a menu item for BlackBerry device users to click to see more 
   //information about the city they select.

   private MenuItem _viewItem = new MenuItem("More Info", 110, 10) 
   {
        public void run() 
        {
             //Store the index of the city the BlackBerry device user selects

             select = choiceField.getSelectedIndex();

             //Display a new screen with information about the
             //city the BlackBerry device user selects

             _infoScreen = new InfoScreen();
             UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(_infoScreen);
        }
   };

   //Create a menu item for BlackBerry device users to click to close 
   //the app.

   private MenuItem _closeItem = new MenuItem("Close", 200000, 10) 
   {
        public void run()
        {
             onClose();
        }
   };


   //Create an inner class for a new screen that displays
   //information about the city a BlackBerry device user selects.

   private class InfoScreen extends MainScreen
   {
        public InfoScreen() 
        {
             super();

             setTitle("Itinerary");


             LabelField login = new LabelField("Employee Itinerary", LabelField.FIELD_HCENTER); 

             Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("img1.jpg");
             EditField statusMsg = new EditField("Status Message", "Update status here");

        }
   }
}
```

Comment: are you testing on emulator or real device? because you don't need to sign applications when using the emulator.

Comment: I am testing it on the emulator but when I click the login button I get the error I mentioned above. Any help?

Comment: You need to debug further this thing. That error is way too generic. At least try to understand which line is throwing the exception. I have had this kind of exception whenever i deal with a null value, so anything inside your application that can be null can be the error thrower

Comment: I tried debugging with the break point in the login code. Every line throws an error "Source not found". Be it a string text to read from the EditField, SoapObject, print.ln anything, it gives back "Source not found". What is this supposed to mean?I am struggling on this for weeks. Note: I am unable to debug now. Whenever I try to debug the simulator opens and half way on load it shuts off itself. I am so lost.

Comment: There is no folder in my project that contains the .asmx file or the .cs file. I am trying to access the .Net Web Service from my app. Should I be having any of these files in my folder for reference or the URL is good enough for reference? Pardon my questions but this is my first BlackBerry app.

Comment: have you tried cleaning up your emulator?

Comment: Yes I have. I do not know why it has suddenly stopped working.

Comment: Hey, I made some progress. The debugger is working again.Updating Device manager might be it. Anyways, I changed my code to navigate to a new window at the end of the web service code to see if it passes through the web service. So it did navigate it to the other window but after 2 secs it threw back the same error. I am trying the debugger to investigate. On the debugger, I cant click on any button on the simulator. There is a pop up that says "Application Error - BlackBerry 9800 Simulator
Error inside JVM:
Access violation reading from 0x00000027".  In eclipse the error is at Thread.run().

Comment: @Sarah you running thread somany times ?

Comment: Hi Guys, I managed to solve this issue by adding the try catch for the main class load. I believe this question has been opened again by @TNR so it will be best if he can comment and ask questions related to it.

Answer (score 2):

### Code Signing

As Th0rndike said, you don't need to sign code to run in the simulator, so that's not your problem (in the simulator).

### Getting the Debugger Working Again

Also, if you're having trouble even setting breakpoints or stepping through your own Java source code, then:

1. Inside the simulator, delete the application as you would on a normal device.
2. Restart the simulator.
3. Try running from Eclipse again.  If it still doesn't work:
4. Inside Eclipse, from the **BlackBerry** menu, choose **Clean Simulator** and then the JRE package whose simulator you're using (e.g. 5.0.0, 6.0.0, etc.)
5. Try running from Eclipse again.  If it still doesn't work:
6. I would try reinstalling Eclipse and the BlackBerry Java plugin (**together** ... rather than installing a non-BlackBerry Eclipse IDE, and then adding the BlackBerry plugin separately).  You can download the full Eclipse + BlackBerry plugin [from this site](https://developer.blackberry.com/java/download/eclipse/).

Keep in mind that you will **not** be able to step *into* Java code that's part of the Java runtime, and RIM libraries.  You do not have the Java *source* for those, only the binary libraries.  So, if you have the line of code:

```
String s1 = "afdafsdasdf";
String substring = s1.substring(0, 10);  // <- can not step IN, can step OVER
MyWidget mw = new MyWidget();
mw.foo();                                // <- can step IN, or OVER
```

you would not be able to step into the second line, because `substring(int,int)` is not your code.  But, you should be able to step into `mw.foo()` without seeing the **"Source Not Found"** errors, assuming `MyWidget.java` is one of your Java source files.

### Finding Where Exceptions are Thrown

If you're running, and having trouble finding out where an uncaught `NullPointerException`  (or other exception) is being thrown, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2632620/119114).  Basically, just put this debug code in your main program (e.g. MyApp.java):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try {
        Application theApp = new MyApp();
        theApp.enterEventDispatcher();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And then, after the `Throwable` is caught, check the Eclipse **Console** window for stack trace information, showing where the exception came from.  Then, debug again, trying to step into that code, and see what's wrong.

But, getting a functioning debugger is an absolute requirement for productive development.  Don't bother with other problems until debugging works for you.

Comment: @TNR did you try this solution?