# Blackberry Facebook SDK NoClassDefFoundError on OS 7.1

Tags: java, facebook, exception, blackberry

When I try to run **Strawberry** application (facebook-bb-sdk-0.8.25), it runs well on BlackBerry OS 5.0, 6.0, and 7.0. But in OS 7.1 it throws exception **NoClassDefFoundError** right after the icon was clicked. Somebody know about this problem please share. Thank you.[image: error-screen]

Comment: Try finding out more about this exception, and adding that information for us to see.  [See the bottom of this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16113945/119114) about catching `Throwable` in your main program.

Comment: As you said in the *comment* you posted as an answer (that was deleted by a mod), you can try building with the 7.0 SDK (which will still allow you to run on a 7.1 device).  Unless you actually **need** some API that was added only in 7.1, I would accept that as a reasonable solution and move on.  [Here was the important link](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/NoClassDefFoundError-only-on-7-1-devices/td-p/1793613) from that deleted "answer".