# Recurring Exception without a stack trace - how to reset?

Tags: java, exception

In my application log (using log4j), I see a NullPointerException, but without the stack trace. I know that as an optimization, when an exception occurs many times - the jvm stops producing the stack trace. The problem is the exception occurred some time ago, and all my logs are filled with the exception without the stack trace. Is there a way to "reset" this mechanism, so the next thrown exception will be printed with the full stack trace? I don't want to restart the application, as it is hard to reproduce this bug, and restarting may cause to "go away"...

Thanks!

Comment: "I know that as an optimization, when an exception occurs many times - the jvm stops producing the stack trace". You know this how?  It's not true.

Comment: it can be because of in catch block only the cause of the exception has been logged

Comment: Yes it is kind of optimization - see the answer of @dogbane. @Jigar - this is not related to the logging, the exception itself has no stack trace.

Comment: There's a similar question with some more information on the subject on SO. Just posting a link so it can be found from here. http://stackoverflow.com/q/2411487/1407656

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Try running with the following JVM property:

```
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
```

From the [Release Notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/relnotes-139183.html#vm):

> The compiler in the server VM now
>   provides correct stack backtraces for
>   all "cold" built-in exceptions. For
>   performance purposes, when such an
>   exception is thrown a few times, the
>   method may be recompiled. After
>   recompilation, the compiler may choose
>   a faster tactic using preallocated
>   exceptions that do not provide a stack
>   trace. To disable completely the use
>   of preallocated exceptions, use this
>   new flag:
>   `-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow`.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds good. Is it possible to enable this flag on the fly for a running java process?

Comment: @duduamar I don't know for certain, but my guess is that you can't.

Comment: @duduamar: There is now an open ticket for changing this flag at runtime - [JDK-8046503 - Ability to reset OmitStackTraceInFastThrow counter](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8046503). Still open though.

Comment: Last comment from JDK-8046503 is discouraging: "Turning off OmitStackTraceInFastThrow at runtime is not enough. The affected methods would also need to be recompiled and StackTraceInThrowable needs to be enabled as well. This is a Will-Not-Fix candidate."