# Exception message is null?

Tags: java, android, exception

I have a `try-catch` statement in my code. In my catch block, I am calling `e.getMessage()` to print the message of the exception. However, `e.getMessage` keeps returning a null value. Interestingly, when I call `e.printStackTrace,` I have no problem printing the stack trace.

Below is my code:

```
try
{
    console = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpsURLConnection.getInputStream()));
}catch(Exception e)
{
    Log.d("Error", "Error Message: " + e.getMessage()); //e.getMessage is returning a null value
    e.printStackTrace(); //this works. is displaying a SocketTimeOutException
}
```

What could be the cause of my problem? How do I solve it?

Comment: what is the problem? the stacktrace and the exception message are two different things, so nothing to solve here IMHO

Comment: @kostja: Aren't they related? I thought the exception message is a brief description of the stacktrace? So if the stacktrace is not null, then the exception message must also contain a value?

Comment: added an answer as it is getting tooo long for comments

Comment: It can also be the case of exception stacktrace optimization as described here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411487/nullpointerexception-in-java-with-no-stacktrace
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659151/recurring-exception-without-a-stack-trace-how-to-reset

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The message and the stacktrace are two distinct pieces of information. While the stackstrace is mandatory, the message is not. Most exceptions carry a message, and it is the best practice to do so, but some just don't and there's nothing to be done to fix it.

You can make it easier for your clients though and provide a message by wrapping the message-less exception or throwing a custom exception with the original exception as the cause. This might look like following.

```
throw new  MyRuntimeException("Socket was closed unexpectedly", e);
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I should have learned it earlier.

Answer (score 13):

SocketTimeOutException is the type of the exception. It's probably just that this exception (or the code throwing it) didn't bother providing a message with the exception, and thought the type of the exception was sufficiently meaningful. Use

```
Log.d("Error", "Error Message: " + e);
```

or

```
Log.d("Error", "Some exception occurred", e);
```

rather than asking the message.

Comment: Thank you! But how do I know if the SocketTimeOutException occurs due to a Connection Timed Out or other reason?

Comment: A SocketTimeoutException "signals that a timeout has occurred on a socket read or accept.". That's what the javadoc says.

Comment: Thanks! Then is it better to just trap SocketTimeOutException? I'm just afraid because just like in ConnectException, there are lot of scenarios that could trigger it. And if I have to display a really specific error message to the user, then I must also check the message of the exception. Not just the name of the Exception only.

Comment: There are not many scenarios: "a timeout has occurred on a socket read or accept". You should know if you're doing a socket read or accept. So you know exactly what happened and where.

Answer (score 3):

`e.printStackTrace()` means the actual stacktrace which is almost always present. A message however not. If you check the Javadoc of the [getMessage()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getMessage%28%29) method, you will notice that it may return null. There will be message if you call the constructor from exception with the String message param [Exception Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html#Exception%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Thanks! So it is possible for the exception message to be null even the exception was thrown by Java/ Android itself (NOT via throw new Exception)? I am calling e.getMessage() because I want to display the error message to the user.

Comment: If you're allowed to throw exception without a message, so is Android. Exception messages are intended for the developer, not for the user. Android code is Java code. You should catch the exception, and display an appropriate error message to the user yourself.

Comment: @JB Nizet: Yes. That is why I also have to know the cause of the exception via its message. My plan is to do something like this: [if (e.getMessage().contains("Connection Timed Out") then display "Connection Timed Out"]. If I won't be able to determine the main cause of the exception, then I won't also be able to display a specific error message for the user.

Comment: The type of the exception and the location where it's thrown are supposed to be sufficient to display a meaningful error message. You shouldn't rely on the message of the exception.

Answer (score 2):

I think the Exception that is thrown in your code has no message. The String is null. But of course you can print the stack trace. These are two different things. You will see the stack trace, but without the message.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that they are separate entities. Just learned about it today. So there are some errors that Java didn't provide a message?

Comment: Yes, the message is only optional. But I think it's not a very good software design to let the message null, because the message helps the user to get more detailed information about the error.

Answer (score 2):

Try to give the exception itself to the logger instead of e.getMessage(). Loggers generally have methods which expect Throwable objects and default configurations (generally) of the loggers prints the stack trace.

Comment: @JB Nizet gives the example of my suggestion.