# can't show caught exception (newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor)

Tags: java, exception, scheduledexecutorservice

for schedule executor:

```
        executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        Runnable ppt = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    processTask();
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    //need to be aware of this exception, no message is outputted
                }
            }
        };
        executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(ppt, 0, 1000/20, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

for processTask method:

```
       private void processTask() {
           try {
             //task business logic
           } catch(SomeOtherException e) {
                 System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                //I want to be aware of this exception also
           }
        }
```

I know the task failed for a reason and I don't want it to continue after that point (I use executor.shutdown() to cancel it).

I just need to know what the error was when the exception is caught. It doesn't seem to do it in the above method.

Thanks in advance for any response.

Comment: Are you sure that the Runnable is actually executing?

Comment: yes, executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay handles that I believe.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ScheduledExecutorService Exception handling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894595/scheduledexecutorservice-exception-handling)

Comment: It should, but it's good to check that your conclusion about why you aren't seeing the stack trace is correct.

Comment: Your code should print something is there is an exception. The only possibilities I can think of: (i) no exception is thrown (ii) the console is not available (iii) you are not looking at the right console (iv) the message of the exception is empty. See the duplicate I point to for a better way to handle exceptions and ScheduledExecutorService.

Comment: you're right, but it definitely executes its just after a while it fails, the code is much longer than the above but I've narrowed it down to not displaying the error.

Comment: what happens is after a while at some point no more subsequent scheduled tasks are run. For message I add a string to the message of the exception so it would still show something even if the message was empty. I'm definitely looking at one and only console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are putting try catch block in process task also that's why any problem in that method will resolve there and if you call shutdown then control would not return to the above method.

```
          Runnable ppt = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                    processTask();
                    } catch(Exception e) {
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

                    }
                }
            };
         executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(ppt, 0, 1000/20, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

In this example you will get '/ by zero exception' and then scheduler will shutdown.

```
       private static void processTask() {
           try {
             //task business logic
               int x=2/0;
           } catch(Exception e) {
                 System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                //I want to be aware of this exception also
                  executor.shutdown();
           }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, this could possibly solve my issue. I'll be back here tomorrow when I've made changes.

Comment: While writing code for methods that can be reuse by other piece/segment of your application or outside of your application use throws keyword to inform/alert to caller of your method for specific Exception to be handled rather than using try-catch block with in method itself. Because different users (or same user at different segments/classes/scenario) may need to display different Error related message according to their need. So it gives a flexibility to all the callers using your method.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `e.printStackTrace()`. `getMessage()` is a method of `Throwable class` (super class of all exceptions of Java) inherited by every exception class like `ArithmeticException`.  The `getMessage()` method prints only the message part(If any message is available) of the output printed by object e. While printStackTrace() method prints full stack trace along with the line number where exception occurred with error message- See more at: http://way2java.com/exceptions/getmessage-printstacktrace/#sthash.QMvLohu3.dpuf

As answered by Kostja [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8613408/exception-message-is-null)

> The message and the stacktrace are two distinct pieces of
>   information. While the stackstrace is mandatory, the message isnt.
>   Most exceptions deliver a message, and it is the best practice, but
>   some just don't and there's nothing to be done to fix it.

For more information you can see similar queries here [link-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8237080/exception-getmessage-is-null) and [link-2](http://www.coderanch.com/t/406999/java/java/Throwable-getMessage).

Comment: Thanks for response, but I'm also adding to the message that I forgot to include in the OP. such as system.out.println(e.getMessage() + " additional info");