# Create NPE without stacktrace

Tags: java, stack-trace

On OS X 10.11 users of our application experience a couple of NPEs without stacktraces (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411487/nullpointerexception-in-java-with-no-stacktrace) stackoverflow-question). I now want to create one myself to debug our error handling in this case.

How to prevent creating the stacktrace?

Comment: If someone can explain me the purpose of this?

Comment: I wanted to debug whether our error code handling handles these stacktrace-less exceptions correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it actually was that simple:

```
final NullPointerException npe = new NullPointerException();
npe.setStackTrace(new StackTraceElement[0]);
throw npe;
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the linked post, the optimization happens when the same code causes the same exception frequently enough. So one way would be to cycle your exception-throwing and error handling code enough times to start seeing the optimization.

Or you can try a hack like this:

```
try {
    throw new NullPointerException("fake");
} catch (NullPointerException e) 
    e.setStackTrace(new StackTraceElement[0]);
    throw e;
}
```

Comment: I've tried cycling > 100000 times but without success, so I've searched a different way.