# java.lang.ClassCastException; no stacktrace with TreeSet<ItemStack>

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

I have this method defined:

```
public static TreeSet<ItemStack> getItems() {
    TreeSet<ItemStack> things = new TreeSet<>();
    things.add(new ItemStack(Material.ACACIA_DOOR));
    return things;
}
```

I also tried putting multiple things in the TreeSet, it doesn't work either.

Now I have this code part:

```
TreeSet<ItemStack> things = getItems();
```

If I run this, nothing happens. If I surround it with try/catch, there seems to be an exception thrown.
But if I print the error like that:

```
} catch (Exception exc) {
    System.out.println("Catched an exception:")
    exc.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println(exc.getMessage());
    System.out.println(exc);
}
```

There isn't any error / Stacktrace or so coming up. It just says:

```
[INFO]: Catched an exception:
[WARN]: java.lang.ClassCastException
[INFO]: null
[INFO]: java.lang.ClassCastException
```

So what is the error, how do I prevent it and why do I get it by casting a TreeSet with ItemSets to a TreeSet with ItemSets?

Comment: Does `ItemStack` implement `Comparable<ItemStack>`? I'm going to guess it doesn't.

Comment: @AndyTurner I think it doesn't:

public class ItemStack
extends Object
implements Cloneable, ConfigurationSerializable

Comment: Right, it doesn't. Note that `extends Object` is unnecessary also.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do, @ScrouthTV?

Comment: @Kerooker making a list with multiple ItemStacks and looping through them at another place

Comment: @AndyTurner Yeah I know, it is unnecessary. I didn't do that, it's premade by Bukkit (API)

Comment: And why do you want to use a TreeSet, not a normal list, for instance?

Comment: You can simply use List<ItemStack> items = new ArrayList<ItemStack>(); and then items.add(new ItemStack....);

Comment: @Kerooker thank you. ;)

Comment: @ScrouthTV Welcome to SO. If you found the answer you were looking for, be sure to accept it with the check.

Comment: As for why there is no stack trace, it's possible that [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2411487/3991344) will explain why that happens (but I'm not sure entirely).

Answer (score 1):

What you can do to solve your situation, and thus guaranteeing your intended behaviour is using a normal list instead of a TreeSet to store your items:

```
ArrayList<ItemStack> items = new ArrayList<ItemStack>();
items.add(new ItemStack(Material.GRASS);
items.add(new ItemStack(Material.DIRT);
//Items is now a list with 2 ItemStacks inside

for (ItemStack is : items) {
    //Do something
}
```

In that way you fix your issue. Treeset should be used if you want a certain ordain on your Items, and ItemStacks cannot be ordered normally.

Answer (score 0):

[Read the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#TreeSet()).

Even if you don't know what you're looking for, hit `Ctrl-f`, and look for `ClassCastException` in the page. In the documentation of the constructor you're using, `TreeSet()`, you'll find:

> All elements inserted into the set must implement the `Comparable` interface. ... If the user attempts to add an element to the set that violates this constraint ..., the add call will throw a `ClassCastException`.

So, either:

- make your `ItemStack` implement `Comparable<ItemStack>`.
- Provide a `Comparator<ItemStack>` to the constructor of the `TreeSet`.

Answer (score 0):

[The docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html), I think maybe the problem is that the item of `TreeSet` should implments `Comparable` or extend 'Comparator'. Hope it can help you out.