# log4j truncates stacktrace

Tags: java, exception, log4j, stack-trace, truncate

I'm having a problem printing the stacktrace to my log file.
Log4j.properties:

```
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=/var/log/app/application.log
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %c{1} [%p] %m%n

log4j.rootLogger=warn, file
log4j.logger.com.app=info, file
log4j.additivity.com.app=false
```

when I log an exception like this in my class UserGuard.java:

```
} catch (Exception e) {
    log.error("Uncaught error", e);
    response.setEntity(new StringRepresentation(" "));
    response.setStatus(Status.SERVER_ERROR_INTERNAL);
}
```

This results in my application.log :

```
2011-12-28 07:30:03 UserGuard [ERROR] Uncaught error
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

No stack trace shown. This is really annoying.
Thanks!

Tried with same pom.xml and same log4j.properties on another machine and works ok. Should I think that the problem is my java version?

Comment: `log4j.additivity.file=false`

Comment: Does the problem still occur if you use a different appender, such as a ConsoleAppender? Have you tried running log4j with debug output enabled so you can see if there are any errors in your log4j config?

Comment: I did try both with no success. See my edit

Comment: Did you check [-Dlog4j.debug](http://jaitechwriteups.blogspot.com/2006/07/know-how-log4j-tries-to-configure.html)? Another option is to unpack sources and use debugger.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your stack traces are most likely getting truncated due to an optimization in Hotspot.  The optimization only builds the identical stacktrace a limited number of times, and then future instances of the exception from the same exact place don't build it.

You can either turn off this optimization using the `-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow` flag, or go back to earlier logs to find the first instance of this exception occuring (it's logged once, then optimized away later).

See this related [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076191/nullpointerexception-stack-trace-not-available-without-debug-agent), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411487/nullpointerexception-in-java-with-no-stacktrace), and this [blog post over here](http://jawspeak.com/2010/05/26/hotspot-caused-exceptions-to-lose-their-stack-traces-in-production-and-the-fix/).

Answer (score 0):

There is an enhancement to log4j:
http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/EnhancedPatternLayout.html

Comment: Didn't find anything useful there