# Can Hotspot JIT optimizations for fast throw exceptions lead to ambiguous results?

Tags: java, jvm-hotspot

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076191/nullpointerexception-stack-trace-not-available-without-debug-agent) deals with cases where the JIT compiler determines that it will no longer generate stacktraces if it deems that it has done so some certain number of times previously. I understand this is known as "fast throw" or "preallocated" exceptions.

Generally speaking if one were to encounter such a preallocated exception, the missing stacktrace should be findable at least once at some earlier point in the JVM's life, before JIT had deemed it worthy of compiling out.

My question is whether the mapping back from a reported occurrence of a preallocated exception to at least one instance of an earlier exception can be guaranteed to be deterministic, and if not, is there any way to avoid this being a source of ambiguity short of disabling the optimization altogether using -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow.

A simplistic example:

The shortened/preallocated exception that gets reported is something generic such as NullPointerException. 
If there was only one type of stacktrace topping out with a NPE in the earlier life of the JVM, then no problem. But what if there was more than one NPE already from various points in code? The JVM does not give any indication which or if any of the earlier stacks have been compiled out, so how could you deterministically establish what the stacktrace would otherwise have been?

Could this circumstance actually arise, or is the modern Hotspot JIT clever enough to avoid creating such an ambiguity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The JVM itself does not try to map these preallocated exception to any previously thrown exception.
You, as a developer, can try to guess where these preallocated exceptions come from but there are no guarantees.

If you are trying to debug something and see stacktrace-less exceptions, the safest thing is to disable the optimization using `-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow` while you try to find the source of the problem.

Comment: Thanks Wooden, its the guesswork that I was hoping wouldnt be necessary.