# Absence of stack trace in a NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, stack-trace

My Java program is failing due to a NullPointerException. Problem is, the exception contains no message and, more frustratingly, no stack trace to help me figure out precisely where it's coming from. Other logs of my program have helped me narrow it down to a general region of code, but the fault still isn't apparent to me.

What would cause a NullPointerException to be devoid of a stack trace? Is the mere fact that the Exception is devoid of any information in itself a hint as to what's going on?

Comment: What is the exact output you're seeing?

Comment: You may find your answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411487/nullpointerexception-in-java-with-no-stacktrace

Comment: You may find your answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411487/nullpointerexception-in-java-with-no-stacktrace http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076191/nullpointerexception-stack-trace-not-available-without-debug-agent

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NullPointerException in Java with no StackTrace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411487/nullpointerexception-in-java-with-no-stacktrace)

Comment: Thanks, RJMIMI38! Turns out all I needed to do was add those extra parameters to the command line to get the proper output!